# Actions on Google - Location Permission

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How do you request device location using webhook, and actions on google v2.

Previously, I used permission_request field, but that is now deprecated, and not sure where it fits into the response object at.

json response

```
{
speech: "",
displayText: "",
data: {
google: {
expectUserResponse: true,
noInputPrompts: [
{
textToSpeech: "Hello McFly!"
},
{
textToSpeech: "Good talk, Russ"
},
{
textToSpeech: "Alright, I'm just gonna go over here and hang out. Let me know if there is anything else I can do for you."
}
],
richResponse: {
items: [
{
simpleResponse: {
textToSpeech: "Testing",
ssml: "<speak >Testing</speak>",
displayText: "Testing"
},
basicCard: null
}
],
suggestions: [ ],
linkOutSuggestion: {
destinationName: null,
url: null
}
},
systemIntent: null,
possibleIntents: [
{
intent: "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
inputValueData: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
optContext: "To provide weather information for you.",
permissions: [
"DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION"
]
}
}
]
}
},
contextOut: [ ],
source: "Abbi"
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the user information helper: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#calling_the_helper

Comment: I am using a c# webhook, so my object is slighting different.  example of the json package that is generated from my webhook can be found https://gist.github.com/NicoSB/ab98b91f033b9be6e09223f597cfae40 And im having trouble figuring out at what level "PossibleIntent" object belongs.

Comment: If you mean ExpectedIntent, then that is documented: https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/webhook#ExpectedIntent

Comment: in the json from the previous example yes, that would appear to be the object that needs to be filled in. However, creating an expectedInput object at that level, does not work, when using v2 in a webhook.  In the examples from the gist link provided, those cards work.  Are you saying that i don't create ExpectedInput object, but instead, put the request for user location permission in as systemIntent?  that documentation also appears to be for version 1, as it is not camelCase, and v2 is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4):

so i needed to add the permission request as a system intent, not expected intent, or possible intent.

the below json works now

```
{
speech: "",
displayText: "",
data: {
google: {
expectUserResponse: true,
noInputPrompts: [
{
textToSpeech: "Hello McFly!"
},
{
textToSpeech: "Good talk, Russ"
},
{
textToSpeech: "Alright, I'm just gonna go over here and hang out. Let me know if there is anything else I can do for you."
}
],
richResponse: {
items: [
{
simpleResponse: {
textToSpeech: "",
ssml: "<speak ></speak>",
displayText: ""
},
basicCard: null
}
],
suggestions: [ ],
linkOutSuggestion: {
destinationName: null,
url: null
}
},
systemIntent: {
intent: "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
data: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
optContext: "To provide an accurate experience, ",
permissions: [
"DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
],
carouselSelect: null
}
}
}
},
contextOut: [ ],
source: "Abbi"
}
```